# Python scikit svm "ValueError: X has 62 features per sample; expecting 337"

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Playing around with Python's scikit SVM Linear Support Vector Classification and I'm running into an error when I attempt to make predictions:

```
ten_percent = len(raw_routes_data) / 10

# Training
training_label = all_labels[ten_percent:]
training_raw_data = raw_routes_data[ten_percent:]
training_data = DictVectorizer().fit_transform(training_raw_data).toarray()


learner = svm.LinearSVC()
learner.fit(training_data, training_label)

# Predicting
testing_label = all_labels[:ten_percent]
testing_raw_data = raw_routes_data[:ten_percent]
testing_data = DictVectorizer().fit_transform(testing_raw_data).toarray()

testing_predictions = learner.predict(testing_data)


m = metrics.classification_report(testing_label, testing_predictions)
```

The raw_data is represented as a Python dictionary with categories of arrival times for various travel options and categories for weather data:

```
{'72_bus': '6.0 to 11.0', 'uber_eta': '2.0 to 3.5', 'tweet_delay': '0', 'c_train': '1.0 to 4.0', 'weather': 'Overcast', '52_bus': '16.0 to 21.0', 'uber_surging': '1.0 to 1.15', 'd_train': '17.6666666667 to 21.8333333333', 'feels_like': '27.6666666667 to 32.5'}
```

When I train and fit the training data I use a Dictionary Vectorizer on 90% of the data and turning it into an array.

The provided testing_labels are represented as:

```
[1,2,3,3,1,2,3, ... ]
```

It's when I attempt to use the LinearSVC to predict that I'm informed:

```
ValueError: X has 27 features per sample; expecting 46
```

What am I missing here? Obviously it is the way I fit and transform the data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you creating and fitting different `DictVectorizer` for train and for test.

You should create and fit only one `DictVectorizer` using train data and use `transform` method of this object on your testing data to create feature representation of your test data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I had similar concern while working with "CountVectorizer".
When I removed the additional fitting done for the Test data and only used "transform" method based on the fitting done for the Training data, it worked liked a gem.

Sharing it if helps the community on similar concerns in predicting the outcome using Test data.

Thanks,
Shabir Jameel